# Android Button Text not getting centered even with includeFontPadding=false

Tags: android, xml, android-button

As mentioned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/640dM.png), I add gravity=center and disabled the includeFontPadding parameter. However, my app button look like that :

[image]

```
<Button
                    android:layout_width="168dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_borders"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/fontpragatinarrow_bold"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="@string/check"
                    android:textSize="21sp" />
```

Edit : If layout_height is switched to wrap_content vs original one(yes, that's green now) :

[image]

Comment: The textSize you have given inside your button is larger than the height of the button. You can change the layout_height to be wrap_content.

Comment: Ehm... textSize=21 > than height= 40 ?
I edit to show the result.

Comment: According to your edit, it seems like it solved your issue.

Comment: @tomerpacific Nope, I want my button's heigt 40dp, not 68. There is more padding than text on my button

Answer (score 0):

Just use "wrap_content" for width and height

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="button"/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLlD9.png)

Comment: thanks, but I want to keep the witdth / height to 168/40. Your solution is around 130 / 70.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="168dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/button_borders"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fontpragatinarrow_bold"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/check"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
```

android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change anything. 18sp only reduce a bit the text "cut"